# Find related audios via Keywords

Tags: objective-c, algorithm, artificial-intelligence, match, keyword

I'm starting to implement an iphone application, that contains audio lessons.
my application is connect to calendar and map, so it takes from the user (places, appointment or meetings) that he wrote in Calendar or checked-in in map.
Then, I will display related lessons to him.
My question is: Is there any algorithm that can be user to find related lesson.
note that each lesson contains keywords and I want to match them with user input.

Thank you and I appreciate any kind of information that will help me :)

Answer (score 1):

i'd just create a separate database which contained an array of keywords and somehow specified its associated audio file resource. IOW, NSArray and NSString should make this pretty quick to implement yourself.

Comment: @Alaa12 well if you have a text file which has all the keywords, then put each on one line (for example), then you could divide them at runtime using `NSArray * keywords = [fileContentsString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];`. then take the keywords array of NSStrings and check which contain the user-entered string.